# Traversing DOM with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

If I have the following div tag...

```
<!doctype html>
<div id="idea">
  <p class="news">hello world!</p>
  <p class="news">hello world!</p>
  <p class="news">hello world!</p>
  <p class="news">hello world!</p>
</div>
```

In jquery, if i want to use the div id to change the last p tag and use the 2nd p element class to change Hello world! to something else. My efforts (which aren't working):

```
  $(document).ready(function) {
    $('#idea:last').html("something else");
  }
  $(document).ready(function) {
    $('.newsbanner[1]').html("something else");
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at your formatting here, you need to indent code by 4 spaces for it to display correctly. Read the information when submitting a question.

Comment: Oh snap, and just like that its updated. Thanks Tom.

Comment: Thanks. any idea on the above?

Comment: Where is the newsbanner class in your HTML?  I only see elements with class "news"

Answer (score 1):

You can use :nth-of-type() Selector. Check this [document](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.news:nth-child(2)').html("something else");
```

Will change the second ".news" html

The example you tried with an array is incorrect. You need to declare the array first. have a read of nth-child recepies from css tricks, they can be useful to find elements in JS.

https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Update:

```
// Selects using CSS selectors the second p element, .text() changed the 
// html elements content and .addClass() adds the class. 
$('#idea p:nth-child(2)').text('something else').addClass('someClass');
// Selects the last element
$('#idea p:last-of-type').text('something else');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/516crdLd/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the first one changes everything when I use the code: $('#newsblock:last-child').html("something else");. The other one, doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ok based on what you have asked:

"You want to use the parents ID to change the last P tags html, and add a class to the second P tag as well as change its text"

Updated my answer.